# Flutter does not find android sdk

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I just tried intalling flutter and since I already had android studio and the android sdk installed I just followed the installation of flutter. Here is my problem: When I run

```
flutter doctor
```

It tells me

```
  [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.248], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.1.5 at C:\Users\Name\git\flutter
    • Framework revision 3ea4d06340 (2 weeks ago), 2018-02-22 11:12:39 -0800
    • Engine revision ead227f118
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759

[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\Android
      but Android SDK not found at this location.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)
```

Which tells me that flutter is not finding my Android sdk (even though it is the path that android studio uses aswell - and android studio is working fine)

I already tried reinstalling the sdk but it did not work.

Im very thankful for any help with this.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

Use :

```bash
flutter config --android-sdk "<path-to-your-android-sdk-path>"
```

Comment: That works. Small addition. I found the sdk in the user folder of my windows 10 as follow :
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\[your Local user folder]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

Comment: yes, you need to enter it with the quotes. eg: flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"

Comment: Thanks a lot. After an hour of figuring out what's wrong finally works now!

Comment: Why do we need to fix things that aren't wrong... can't they just add that statement during the setup? All those little things really annoy me.

Comment: just set the ANDROID_HOME env to appropriate location

Comment: that's my boy. Worth saying you need to install with `sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-X" "build-tools;X" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository"`. Otherwise you are pointing into the right directory but there's no SDK and flutter will complain.

Answer (score 43):

Kindly first of all check your latest sdk
first step:
[image: install latest Sdk platform]

second step:
[image: Install all these licenses]

Now Run

> run flutter doctor --android-licenses
>   Press Y against each agreement

run flutter doctor
[image: flutter doctor]
it will work fine.

Comment: Your answer does not tell what a user should do. Your answer suggests that they should update all the SDK and tools according to your images.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which of these I performed that made flutter doctor finally prompt me to accept licences, but yes, now everything finally passes.  I believe it may have been installing SDK platform api level 28, Android SDK tools (initial install only downloaded Platform-Tools.  Once those were installed and I re-ran flutter doctor --android-licenses again, it all worked out.  This process (to be able to develop Flutter) needs to be improved, imho.  Is it worth the effort (rhetorical)?

Comment: Thanks. Somehow i skipped installing platform tool..worked thereafter

Comment: The accepted answer is particularly useful when android sdk was located somewhere other than the path specified in the flutter doctor error. By default, the answer above this comment should solve most android sdk issues with flutter. Keep sdk fully installed/updated as possible. Also, the accept licenses should be automatic.

Answer (score 21):

Choose the folder to install (I called it `BASE_PATH`) and use the following commands to install SDK with flutter:

**Install SDK**

```
cd $BASE_DIR
mkdir android-sdk
cd android-sdk
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip
unzip commandlinetools-linux-6200805_latest.zip
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$(pwd) "build-tools;28.0.3" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "tools"
```

I used a separate folder for SDK, because it will add parent folders.

**Install Flutter**

```
cd $BASE_DIR
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable.tar.xz
tar xvf flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable.tar.xz
```

**Export Vars** (you can add them to your `.bashrc`)

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$BASE_DIR/android-sdk
export ANDROID_PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
export FLUTTER=$BASE_DIR/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH:$FLUTTER
```

**Check!**

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.12.13, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I had to do `flutter config --android-sdk="$ANDROID_SDK"` (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90042#issuecomment-919075876) to make it work

Comment: thanks....the best answer over the internet
just pass the --sdk_root flag with every sdk manager commmand , and after installing build tools and command liine tools, just set the ANDROID_HOME env
flutter reads that only

Comment: In my case, I had to add "cmdline-tools;latest" as well when installing SDK

Answer (score 9):

I have got following issue on Flutter Doctor command.

**X Android SDK file not found: ..\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.**

to fix this just go to *Tools=> Android Sdk =>Update Sdk Platform* for which issue is there.(I installed SDK 28).

[check flutter document for this issue](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#get-the-flutter-sdk)

Comment: The issue happens when the "latest" sdk platform found on the sdk directory was only partially installed or was incomplete and literally android.jar is not present. Make sure when you completely install any sdk platform for every new API you desire to use.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't find the proper SDK path then,

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to Tools
3. Go to SDK Manager
4. You will find the "Android SDK Location"

Copy the path and edit "the Environment Variable"
After that, restart and run the command.
Then, run "flutter doctor"
Hope, it will work!

Answer (score 7):

In my SDK folder there were a empty folder (/build-tools/29.0.0)

I deleted it, and it worked fine

Comment: This worked for me on Mac machine. Simply delete empty folder. Thanks Xero

Comment: Yes, this works, and it will 'revert' to the next 'latest' API level present in the platform directory. It can be fully fixed by installing partially install sdk platform package again in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 7):

I spent a lot of time solving this.

Eventually what worked was going to project settings in android studio, sdk tools, uncheck hide obsolete packages and install sdk tools obsolete package.

Then run flutter doctor --android-licenses and then flutter doctor showed a green tick on my android toolchain.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Another non-sensical thing... why is it active if then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

**For mac users,**

It was working fine yesterday, now the hell broke. I was able to fix it.

My issue was with ANDROID_HOME

```
// This is wrong. No idea how it was working earlier.
ANDROID_HOME = Library/Android/sdk
```

If you did the same, change it to:

```
ANDROID_HOME = /Users/rana.singh/Library/Android/sdk
```

**.bash_profile** has

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/rana.singh/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 4):

Flutter say Sdk build tool version(exp:android toolchain - develop for android devices (android sdk 28.0.3)) version=28.0.3
go to home/username/Android/Sdk/build-tools 
delete this version(28.0.3) and fixed bug

Answer (score 4):

To open Tools=> Android Sdk[image]
Click SDK tools tab => check show package details and check all 28 SDK version
install that and to fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

Flutter is designed to use the latest Android version installed. So if you have an incomplete download of the latest Android, Flutter will try to use that.

So either complete the installation or delete the complete installation. You can find the Android versions at: `/home/{user}/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar`

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio Code and Flutter 3.3.3. The above answers did not work for me. I followed the below steps to solve the problem:

- Downloaded the latest Android command-line tools from https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools
- Unzipped the downloaded .zip file and went inside the extracted folder
- Executed the below command in command-prompt (as administrator) to install the Android SDK packages:

  *bin\sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=<android_sdk_path> "build-tools;28.0.3" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "tools" "cmdline-tools;latest" "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86"*

> *"system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86"* is needed for
> adding device emulator

- Set the Android SDK path for flutter:

  *flutter config --android-sdk <android_sdk_path>*
- Accept the Android licenses for flutter:

  *flutter doctor --android-licenses*

You are done. You can verify the installation using *`flutter doctor`* command. You should see something like this:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2006], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.5)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 categories.
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is this known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13750

You need to fix the path to the SDK manually until this is fixed
in the file

```
my_flutter_project/android/local.properties
```

**update**

Add `$ANDROID_HOME\sdk\tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME\sdk\platform-tools` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: First of all thatks a lot for your anwer. I did not exactly understand where the local.properties folder is located.

Comment: In you flutter project directors (`my_flutter_project` is the name I assumed) there is an `android` sub-directory that contains the file.

Comment: I have only one flutter project created which only contains one directory (called .idea) which contains one xml file (called workspace).

When I created this project in android studio there where no files to access.

Comment: That dorsn't sound like you created it using `flutter create`. I guess you created it from the IDE and something went wrong. Can you try from command line?

Comment: Yes I did create it in the IDE in the first place. Now I tried to create it using flutter creat - which finally worked. But when I run flutter doctor the same error message still appears. I also tried changing the local.proerties file. Ich changed the android sdk location to the location that my android sdk manager in android studio is using. Since android studio works I think that should work aswell. But the same error message still appears when I use flutter doctor and it does not find my smartphone when I try to run the flutter project.

Comment: `adb devices` does list your device?

Comment: I can run native android apps in my android studio with my smartphone - so i guess yes

Comment: I guess it doesn't make sense to try anything like that as long as `flutter doctor` reports errors, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes but I dont get why it tells me that it is not finding my sdk - since it is working with android studio and I even deleted it and re-downloaded it. The path is also the same that my newly downloaded sdk and android studio are using

Comment: This issue is still not fixed, but I just ignored flutter-doctor and set up my Android Studio devices. Then I created the project from inside VSCode and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

First open Android SDK Manager and make sure the required SDK's are installed.

[image]

Now open SDK manager, copy the SDK path. Open cmd

```
cd C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools
```

now again Change dir to the inner folder in build-tools.
check the presence or the name issues of the aapt.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding the Android SDK path didn't help.

I deleted all my SDKs (basically just deleted that Android folder. Used this path "C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Android" to locate it.)

I then reinstalled all the required SDKs using android studio. (Be sure to install more than 1 SDK, I don't know why it doesn't work if you only install 1).

Then if I run Flutter Doctor, every thing works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `ANDROID_HOME` variable to SDK.

Create a new variable by the name and set it to the installation directory.

Make sure SDK is not below 2 subfolders from c drive or any windows root drive.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by below step,

1) go to -> system environment -> Environment Variables -> system Variable

2) create New Variable Name **ANDROID_HOME** and Value **D:\Androidsdk\tools** (custom android sdk path).

3) concat this path **D:\Androidsdk\platform-tools** in **Path** variable value using ";". (also in system Variable)

4) that's all, Restart the PC to apply changes and try again -- flutter Doctor.

Answer (score 2):

This article explained how to solve it through Android Studio, since you don't need to install the SDK Manager separately when you use Android Studio.
REFERENCE: https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-command-line-tools-component-is-missing/

1. Open Android Studio
2. More Actions >>> SDK Manager
3. Android SDK >>> SDK Tools
4. Check "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) >>> OK
5. Restart your command line window and run `flutter doctor` again to verify

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Android Studio installed, only VS Code and extract sdk in `C:\Android\`.

For solution, I'm set directly path:

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Android\cmdline-tools\latest\bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

```
flutter config --android-sdk < path to your sdk >
```

OR

> If you are facing this issue --> sdk file is not found in android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.

You may have probably not installed build tools for this Api level, Which can be installed through this link https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools

Answer (score 0):

First run flutter upgrade from your terminal ,
If you get the following error,

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\Android
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
```

1. First go to android studio, Settings->System Settings->Click the expand arrow
2. Then go to the Android SDK option and add the corresponding SDK to the project then go to Project Structure and add the respective SDK to the project Structure
3. Then run flutter upgrade in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

We need to manually add the Android SDK. The instructions in the flutter.io/download say that the Android Studio 3.6 or later needs the SDK to be installed manually. To do that,

1. Open the **Android Studio SDK Manager**
2. In the **Android SDK tab**, uncheck Hide Obsolete Packages
3. Check **Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)**

Please refer the [Android Setup Instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup).

Answer (score 0):

What worked is Tools->Flutter->open Android module in Android studio, For me plugin flutter_email_sender was giving this error, so I copied local.properties file into it and the build become successful.
[image]

Or
Open Terminal
Run touch `~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<macusername>/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/<macusername>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Run `source ~/.bash_profile` in **android studio terminal**

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

- Step 1: In search type show hidden files and enable it.
- Step 2: Go to C directoy> users>
- Step 3: In that navigate to AppData>Local>Android>Sdk
- Step 4: Copy the path to this folder
- Step 5: Open power-shell and type in:

`flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\<folder under your name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"`

Answer (score 0):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Development/android_sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools


export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/pathto/flutter_sdk/bin
```

`PWD this won't work I guess

goes in .zprofile or .zshrc un the respective user directory of mac

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem in windows, and It's come while authorizing android licenses.   flutter doctor --android-licenses[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Eln.png)

for resolving this issue we only have to install Android SDK command-line Tools(Latest)
Open **Android Studio->files->Settings->Appearence & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK->SDK Tools->(install) Android SDK command-line Tools(Latest)**

Comment: This solves a different issue that might be found when command line tools is not present/not updated, but the question stated android studio (and sdk manager) was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

go to local.properties in project/android/local.properties
change this

> `sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\ACER\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

to

> `sdk.dir=A:\\yoursdkfolder\\sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions and spent a lot of time then finally I removed the error by following steps-

1. [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3) X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3
2. delete this folder inside build-tools (because the error is not installed properly).
3. for resolving this issue, we have to uncheck all the latest plateforms (android (S)12 etc) and click apply after this restart the studio and check all these platforms again at least one latest and apply(ok).
4. Open Android Studio->files->Settings->Appearence & Behavior->System
   Settings->Android SDK->SDK plateforms(Latest)
   [image]

5. run flutter command to accept the licenses. (type Y  then enter for all)
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
6. run flutter doctor ( all is done).

Regards!
Dinesh Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

I tried the best answer but it didn't work for me.

Running `flutter doctor-v` gave me a tip that worked.

Just run `flutter config --android-studio-dir=`

It will ask you to restart VS Code again.

Delete the terminal in VS Code and restart VS Code.

Run `flutter doctor-v` again and the issues was sorted for me.