# No valid Android SDK platforms

Tags: flutter

When I write flutter doctor command in cmd I get this error.

```
No valid Android SDK platforms found in G:\SdkManager\platforms. Candidates were:
- android-21
- android-27
- android-28
- android-8.0.0
```

flutter doctor 
[image: flutter doctor]

env 
[image: env]

path 
[image: path]

flutter sdk 
[image: flutter sdk]

platforms 
[image: platforms]

plugins 
[image: plugins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download all sdk from file-> settings -> sdkmanager.
And do not download manually.

Answer (score 22):

It appears as though this message shows up when you don't have any `build-tools` packages installed.  At the time of writing, to install the minimum required versions, you can fix this issue with:

```sh
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-30" "build-tools;30.0.3"
```

Answer (score 4):

I've set up my Android SDK manually on Windows 10 with the command line and I was able to solve this kind of errors while I tried to set up my development environment, if you want to solve it as I did, just follow the next steps that I posted in a GitHub Comment in a related issue:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19805#issuecomment-478306166

Answer (score 2):

You should download and install Android build tools for the respective platform versions. This can be done via the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by only installing **Android SDK Build-Tools 35-rci** in **SDKManager > SDKTools** as shown in image Below

"[Solution Image][1]

See this Image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJGH3.png

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidStudio go to menu Tool > Android > SDK Manager
On the tab "SDK Platforms" select one or more platforms and click the OK button.
Wait until the download completed and try again.

Comment: I did it, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/PIWpLOlRExE and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/m7geeKPyJ_U if there are suggestions that apply for your case. Either you have a wrong path set to `ANDROID_HOME` or in the Flutter plugin or your Android SDK setup is incomplete.

Comment: I still have the same problem , please see the images that i sent

Answer (score 0):

Find your sdk path and execute the code.

```
$ flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk/55512823)

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is incorrect in environment variable.
You should change it to G:/Sdkmanager/platforms