# Android studio not found, by flutter. What is this

Tags: android, flutter

As you can see in the image below Flutter cant find android studio while I just installed it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltr8P.png)

Comment: As the error message says, the Java SDK is not found, as you have no `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article for how to modify the path to android studio if you haven't installed it to the default location, which I'm guessing is your problem:

[Flutter does not find android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk)

You also haven't installed the Flutter and Dart plugins as indicated by your flutter doctor errors.