# Not found 'X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.'

Tags: flutter, installation, windows-10

I have installed flutter on windows10
and set environment variables successfully
and installed android studio with their all sdk
but when i perform the command `flutter doctor` throw me this error.
i browsed for it and got some answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk)) and applied that too but nothing happend.

```
√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.47.1)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: You have to configure android sdk paths and android home path too

Comment: Thank you for response  but I understood the problem and solved it myself, 
you can check my below answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if Android SDK Build-Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools & Android SDK Tools (Obsolete) are installed?

Comment: all installed , BTW i resolved it, Actually I had to install latest sdk platform which api level is 30, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it.
Actually flutter needs latest SDK platforms means android 10.0+ (R) and API Level: 30 which hadn't installed that's why, was throwing this error `X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\smart\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-30\android.jar.`

To solving this:

-open android studio

-goto configure

-choose SDK Manager

-select Android SDK

-select Android 10.0+ (R) , API Level:30 (because for now it is latest)

-apply for download

after downloaded just run command `flutter doctor`
and then issue will be gone.