# path error of android not found in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am facing a problem suddenly can anyone help me with this?
I am new to android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your OS can't find the SDK location this might help [Flutter does not find android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk?rq=1)

if not let me know

Comment: Please ensure Java is in your PATH and that JAVA_HOME is defined and pointing to the JDK

Comment: can your share what is in the PATH of PC??

Comment: for JAVA_HOME => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202 and in path=> C:\Users\PALAK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms

Comment: the android path should be path=>C:\Users\PALAK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: have you installed the android studio on the same location??

Comment: also are you using ANDROID_HOME as the variable name for the path in Environment variable???