# Android toolchain - develop for Android devices and android SDK not found

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

Can anyone help me to solve the *Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X ANDROID_HOME = D:\android-studio-ide-193.6626763-windows.exe
but Android SDK not found at this location.* I already add the path in windows environment.
[image]

Comment: did you have sdk in your pc ?

Comment: @JanviPatel i have it  _C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path directing to executable for running android studio not for sdk, you must find your sdk directory and pointing the to that, for windows user in default path is `"C:\Users\{yourUser}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"`

Comment: I find my SDK directory ready _C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk_ after this I need to do what? I'm new for flutter

Comment: and then try to use this command https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926825/9750548