# I have a problem to run my flutter project in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, windows-10

Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.

Comment: try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596943/flutter-app-could-not-locate-aapt-while-building

Answer (score 0):

This Error is because the flutter does not find the SDK path. You just need to set the SDK Path by following the command using the terminal.

`flutter config --android-sdk sdk_path`