# Flutter: Why "Could not locate aapt." when build-tools actually exist?

Tags: android, flutter, build, sdk, driver

Here is the problem:

```
Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

But just like the picture, aapt is here [image]. I have reinstalled it, but it counldn't be found.

With the similar question, when run `flutter doctor`, an error occurred:

```
cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
```

But as the picture, [image], the latest cmdline-tools is here.

By the way, I reinstalled the win10OS yesterday, so maybe it lacks some drivers. So could anyone tell me what may be the wrong with my build-tools and cmdline-tools? Or, what drivers may related to them, so I can complete installing them.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter app could not locate aapt while building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596943/flutter-app-could-not-locate-aapt-while-building)

Answer (score 1):

This Error is just because you moved SDK from one location to another, and your project SDK path is old. so you just need to update the SDK location for your project. Apply this command in your studio terminal.

flutter config --android-sdk SDK_PATH

for example

flutter config --android-sdk F:\Sdk