# Error Running the Application on Android Mobile

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I was working on a small flutter project suddenly I couldn't run the app to any android mobile.
(on Web it's running Perfectly).
It Shows this Error:

```
    Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x86.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

How can I solve this Error
Thanks A Lot

This is my Gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596943/flutter-app-could-not-locate-aapt-while-building

Comment: Thank you @VinamraJaiswal I searched and Try this solution but it down't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the issue Android SDK file not found: `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\aapt.`

I had already tried other solutions but this worked for me . In `SDK Manager` , go to `SDK tools` , and check the checkbox "Show the various packages" and uncheck "Hide obsolete packages"

Now under `Android SDK Build-tools 31` , install `31.0.0` and apply Under `Android SDK Command-line tools` (latest), install `Android SDK Command-line tools` (obsolete)

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
flutter doctor -v
```

usefull

Comment: Hey @lighto thank you for your suggestion but this error log shows:
X Android SDK file not found: D:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0\aapt.