# Flutter not detecting sdk cmdline tools

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, development-environment

Running flutter doctor gives me the "cmdline-tools component is missing" error, even though I installed Android SDK command-line tools in android studio, I also updated it and am sure it's the latest version. I've been searching for days for a solution to this and the only answer I can find anywhere is "Just install SDK Command-line tools in the Android studio SDK manager!" Which I clearly already did, and it still isn't working.

Images below to specify

[The Flutter Doctor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbMhq.png)

[Showing I have Android SDK Command line installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWDbU.png)

Comment: you need to follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk then run flutter doctor command again

Answer (score 0):

try updating your cmdline tools to latest version

```
sdkmanager.bat --update "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

type this command with in the cmdline-tools > bin path

or try

```
sdkmanager --update "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

this command in cmd

Comment: Actually this is not solve when we install cmdline-tools manually from android studio website because it will install the new one