# i got Missing SDK error while installing android studio on my mac.. how do i solve this?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

[i got Missing SDK error while installing android studio on my mac.. how do i solve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnQij.jpg)

Comment: You check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

it'ss seem like that you haven’t download and configured android sdk yet.
Try to download a android sdk and configure it with this command -

`flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`