# How to change the default Android SDK location in VS Code

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-2.3

**How to change the default Android SDK location in VS Code**

I develop Flutter with VS Code ,I want to change Android SDK location from VS Code for dev Flutter,

I searched but did not find anything.

just android sdk location not flutter sdk location!

Comment: Check that your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable is correct. Alternatively, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926825) may be what you're looking for.