# Linux Flutter Android SDK Missing

Tags: flutter

I've installed Android Studio and the SDK seems to be working fine. Android Studio says that the SDK it's using is `~/Android/Sdk`.

I've tried following the solutions in [this][1] answer. (Mainly running `flutter config --android-sdk "~/Android/Sdk"` [and expanding the path].) I initially had installed flutter with `snap` but then later installed it via [manual installation][2] (to be extra sure).

When I run `flutter doctor`, I get this output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-39-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] VS Code (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

When I try to run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I get this error:

```
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

I manually installed cmdline-tools in the `~/Android/Sdk` folder, and it is present.

I have been able to manually run the `sdkmanager` by setting the `--sdk_root` path manually:

```
~/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=~/Android/Sdk --licenses
```

But Flutter still says that I haven't accepted the android-licenses
Any thoughts?
Thanks so much!
[1]: [Flutter does not find android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175231/flutter-does-not-find-android-sdk)
[2]: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#method-2-manual-installation

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
flutter config --android-sdk "<path-to-your-android-sdk-path>"
```

Note that the path should be within quotes. Flutter lets you add the android sdk with commands.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo! Thanks for the help. That was one of the things I tried (but I just tried it again to be sure). It hasn't seemed to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter) to add the command line tools from Android Studio instead of manually from the website. Then, running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` worked!