# flutter installation error generated while giving fluctor doctor command

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools

This error being generated even after I installed sdk and set the environment variables

```
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices  X ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\saanvi gandhi\OneDrive\Desktop\flutter\ANDROID SDK       but Android SDK not found at this location.
```

I installed androidsdk tools platform and platforms tools are already set
want to run flutter

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49175231/8144311